# iOS - Provide option to change the browser in UIWebView control

Tags: ios, xcode, browser, uiwebview

I have a business requirement, I have just using `UIWebView` control to view specific site on iPad. However, assuming that user installed various browsers (safari, firefox, chrome) on the device, the app should provide option for user to select the browser. Can someone help me how to achieve this in Xcode 5.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can not embed other app components in your App. [But you could launch their app by custom url scheme](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html). UIWebview belongs to UIKit Framework in iOS. For that you must know the custom url scheme of any browser to launch.

Edit:
Safari can use a standard open URL scheme.

Check out: [Google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links) for info on how to use the Google Chrome URL scheme to open your link.

Comment: Thank you for your Input. If I understand you correctly, I cannot use UIWebView control to open the URL using Chrome. The option you suggested, will just open the URL in Chrome browser (if installed already). In that case, is there anyway the Output will be similar to UIWebView (no Address Bar, no Status Bar, nothing).

Comment: The chrome application is standalone, you can not configure like so.